# Display Report Contents Where Column A Equal B in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

[image: Customer Table]

From the image above, I want viewers of my SSRS report to see data where PaymentFound column is equal to 'N' without limiting it in my T-Sql query and without hiding any column in my report.

How do I achieve this in SSRS?

Comment: Is this possible or not in SSRS?

Comment: What you want to show rows or columns ? So in above scenario row with paymentid `11,15,12` should be visible and other rows will be hide right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to hide the rows for which the `PaymentFound` value is `Y`.
There are 2 ways to do that,

1) Add filter on dataset so it will filter the values out with `PaymentFound= Y`

You can add filter as,
    Dataset->RightClick-> DatasetProperties->Filter->Add-> then

```
 Expression : PaymentFound 
 Operator:  =
 Value: 'N'
```

2) Right click on row set the expression for the visibility as

```
= IIF(Fields!PaymentFound.Value = "Y",True,False)
```